# If statement with multiple conditions but only check others if first fails

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to test two conditions, but only want to check the second condition if the first one fails. One example could be:

```
if df is None or len(df) == 0:
     # do something
```

I know I can use two seperate if statements or a try...except block. However, I want to know if there is a more elegant pythonic way of doing it or is two seperate if statements the only way.

Comment: Your example code will run just like you described, what is the problem?

Comment: What you describe is the definition of an `elif`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`or` is a [short-circuit operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) in python 3. This means the second condition (here `len(df) == 0`) is executed only if the first one (here `df is None`) is false.

Answer (score 0):

You can running your code like this:

```
if df == none:
    # Do this

elif len(df) == 0:
    # Do this

else:
    # Do this
```

It works fine and can definately help